# What emulator does Android Studio use?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, android-studio, android-emulator

This question has many parts.

Some info about my system:
64-bit Ubuntu Linux

I am wondering what the stock emulator is that comes with Android Studio (A.Studio) (if indeed it has a name).

A helpful answer would include comparing this emulator with other emulators. A list of pros and cons of using each different emulator would also be helpful.

Perhaps there is a more fundamental ~thing~ about using different emulators; information on that is welcome if anything comes to mind.

Finally, i have never used an emulator besides the one that has come with Eclipse or A.Studio. What do I need to know in order to plug any emulator into any IDE? I have had issues with IDEs being "fragile" and breaking frequently, FYI.

Comment: use genymotion. best emulator i have ever use

Answer (score 1):

You can use `genymotion`, for fast speed the quality, both for the eclipse and Android studio, get it [here](https://www.genymotion.com/?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter#!/).

Also you can set up the `Google play service` for using Google Maps and downloading apps from Google play store.

Get the package and how it use it , please refer to [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145).

Answer (score 1):

The emulator used by Android Studio is the exact same one used with Eclipse. It is in fact included with the Android SDK (which is in turn included in Android Studio) and used by various development environments.

The way it works depends on what kind of **system image** you use it with. For most recent Android versions, there are 2-4 different system images - arm, arm 64-bit, x86, and x86 64-bit (the 64-bit ones are Lollipop only, and fairly experimental at this stage of the game [early 2015]).

There are also Google API versions of these images (they include various Google apps such as Google Play Services) which can be used if these components are needed by your app.

For development purposes, the x86 system images are your best bet as performance is vastly improved by the emulator not having to emulate the ARM architecture - you need to use HAXM (by intel, also available in the Android SDK) to get any real speed benefits with x86 images though. The emulator also provides GPU acceleration (it must be manually enabled for each emulator device) which allows it to use your physical GPU for rendering instead of emulating these operations in software.

The way the development environment (Android Studio) connects to the emulator is via ADB (Android Debug Bridge). This means that it can work with virtually any emulator (such as Genymotion, which runs via VirtualBox). However, there is native support for using the Android Emulator from within Android Studio (this is configured by selecting **emulator** in the Run/Debug configuration)...when using another emulator (such as Genymotion) you should select **USB device** (in Run/Debug configuration) and make sure that the ADB instance is connected to your emulator via TCP (Genymotion does this for you automatically at startup).

This should give you enough information and I will not re-post all the various instructions on how to do any of the above as they have been posted as answers to various questions here on SO.